# AttributeError: 'course' object has no attribute 'grade'

Tags: python, class, oop

I am currently learning the basics of Object Oriented Programming in python. I'm trying to make a class that gets the students' name, age, and grade. And a class named "course" that adds the students that are enrolled in a course, and I want to get the average grades of the students enrolled in a course. here is the code:

```
class students:
    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

class course:
    def __init__(self, name, max_students):
        self.name = name
        self.max_students = max_students
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        if len(self.students) < self.max_students:
            self.students.append(students)
            return True
        return False

    def get_average_grade(self):
        value = 0
        for student in self.students:
            value += students.get_grade(self)

        return value / len(self.max_students)


s1 = students("carlos", 18, 93)
s2 = students("gabriele", 19, 98)
s3 = students("clark", 19, 67)

course1 = course("calculus", 2)
course1.add_student(s1)
course1.add_student(s2)

print(course1.get_average_grade())
```

And this is what it says in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test_repo1\test.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(course1.get_average_grade())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test_repo1\test.py", line 25, in get_average_grade
    value += students.get_grade(self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test_repo1\test.py", line 8, in get_grade
    return self.grade
AttributeError: 'course' object has no attribute 'grade'
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python it's a good habit to always name your objects (classes) in uppercase. This will not only make your code cleaner, but easier to deal with. Here is the working code with modifications:

```py
class Students:  # Uppercase modification.
    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade


class Course:  # Uppercase modification.
    def __init__(self, name, max_students):
        self.name = name
        self.max_students = max_students
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        if len(self.students) < self.max_students:
            self.students.append(student)  # You meant 'student' not 'students'.
            return True
        return False

    def get_average_grade(self):
        value = 0
        for student in self.students:
            value += student.get_grade() # You meant 'student' not 'students'. You do not pass 'self' in here.

        return value / self.max_students  # max_students is already an int. You cannot take the length of an int.


# Uppercase modification.
s1 = Students("carlos", 18, 93)
s2 = Students("gabriele", 19, 98)
s3 = Students("clark", 19, 67)

course1 = Course("calculus", 2)  #  Uppercase modification.
course1.add_student(s1)
course1.add_student(s2)

print(course1.get_average_grade())
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* this fixes the problem?

Comment: Every line that was modified has a comment. The _why_ in some of them are either written or trivial. Perhaps the only non-trivial one is `students.get_grade(self)`.

Comment: The text at the top of your answer implies that the "solution" is related to using upper case, when the code can be fixed w/o changing the case of anything (by applying all of the other modifications you highlight).

Comment: I was just pointing out a good habit to have. I'm sorry man, but this seems like nitpicking criticism. I'll gladly take any constructive criticism, but I think it's fair to say that when OP scrolls through the code (or pastes it in his/her editor) he/she will see the comments marking.

Comment: That's how *I* read it, so it seems plausible that *someone* else might, too (and not even look for "other modifications").  If, instead, the text above the code block just said "Here is the working code with modifications highlighted:", and the helpful comment about capitalization was placed after it, each would be more clearly conveyed (IMHO).